# Como fazer uma lista de chamada com radiobox com o laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Olá, sou iniciante no laravel e estou fazendo um projeto para uma escola cujo uma das funcionalidades do projeto é fazer uma lista de de presença dos alunos. Onde será listado os alunos de uma determinada turma em uma tabela que terá os campos de radio box para marcar a presença ou a ausência de cada aluno.
Estou com dificuldades nessa parte de listar os alunos e marcar a sua presença. Tinha feito uma classe `Frequencia_conteudo.php`onde tinha os atributos `(turma_id, aluno_id, atividades_ministadas, presenca, data)` só que resolvi desmembrar essa classe fazendo uma de `Conteudo` e outra de `Presenca` onde cada uma tem os respectivos atributos `(turma_id, atividades_ministardas, data)` e `(turma_id, conteudo_id, aluno_id, presenca)`. O que se diz a respeito de `Conteudo` já está pronto e funcionando corretamente, só que ao submeter a inclusão do conteúdo eu já estou pedindo para redirecionar para a "lista de chamada", mostro abaixo o store do ConteudoController:

```
public function store(ConteudoRequest $request){
    $novo_frequencia = $request->all();
    Conteudo::create($novo_frequencia);
    return view('presenca.create');
}
```

No controller da Presença está assim o metodo de create:

```
public function create($turma_id){
    Conteudo::find($turma_id);
    $presenca = Conteudo::query()
        ->join('turmas', 'turmas.id', '=', 'conteudos.turma_id')
        ->join('turmas', 'turmas.id', '=', 'turma_alunos.turma_id')
        ->where('turmas.id', '=', $turma_id)->get();
    return view ('presenca.create', ['presenca'=> $presenca]);
}
```

Eu pedi para que puxasse o id da turma que foi cadastrado o Conteúdo, e fiz essa query para buscar os alunos da turma selecionada que ficam salvos em `turma_alunos`.
A view do create de Presença está assim:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<!-- Fonts -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="box box-primary">

            <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Lista de Presença</h3>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Turma: </label>
                            <label>{{$presenca->turma->descricao}}</label></div>

                            <label>Professor Responsável: </label>
                            <label>{{$presenca->turma->oficina->professor->nome}}/label>
                    </div>

                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <input action="{{route('presenca.store')}}" method="post" id="presenca">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
                            <thead>
                            <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
                                <th>Aluno</th>
                                <th>Presença</th>
                            </tr>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                          @foreach($presenca as $alu)
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="aluno_id">{{$alu->aluno->nome}}</td>
                                    <td id="presenca">
                                    <td><input type="radio" name="presenca" id="presenca" value="P" checked>Presente</td>
                                    <td><input type="radio" name="presenca" id="presenca" value="A">Ausente</td>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Finalizar">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Porém o quando vou testá-lo o laravel me retorna esse erro:

Undefined variable: presenca (View: C:\Users\WinSeven\Desktop\sischool\resources\views\Presenca\create.blade.php)

Mesmo eu passando a `$presenca`quando chamo a view. Não sei se seria esse o erro, ou se fiz algo errado, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

ps: estou usando o Laravel 5.5 e PHP 7.0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque

```
return view ('presenca.create', ['presenca'=> $presenca]);
```

Por

```
return view ('presenca.create')->with('prensenca',$presenca);
```

E na view logo no começo para debugar, utilize um

```
@php
    dd(presenca);
    exit;
@endphp
```

Comment: Tentei fazer oque me sugeriu e agora me retornou o erro: Use of undefined constant presenca - assumed 'presenca' (View: C:\Users\WinSeven\Desktop\sischool\resources\views\Presenca\create.blade.php)

Comment: A possibilidade de sua consulta estar errada, foque em debugar ela primeiro, usando o dd(), dentro do controller

Comment: Realmente minha consulta estava com erro, muito obrigada Lucas!